# In Tritium, how do I transform all <p> tags to <div> tags?

Tags: moovweb, tritium

I’m working in the Moovweb SDK and am optimizing my personal desktop site for mobile.

How do I transform all my `<p>` tags to `<div>` tags? I really don't want to do it manually! Search and replace?? haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the name() function to change the name of an element. For example:

```
$("//p") {
    name("div") 
}
```

See it in action here: http://tester.tritium.io/bd1be4f2c187aed317351688e23f01127d26343a

Answer (score 3):

Cheap way: Add `p{margin:0}` to your CSS, this will remove the only special styling of `<p>` tags making them look like `<div>`s.

This is only a visual effect, though. For instance, you're still not allowed to put a `<form>` inside a `<p>`, even with the above CSS. If that's what you're after, a simple search and replace will do:

- Replace `<p>` with `<div>`
- Replace `<p␣` (left angle, p, space) with `<div␣` (there's a space at the end of that one too)
- Replace `</p>` with `</div>`

That should do it!